# @Query annotation in spring data mongodb repository syntax

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-MongoDB. I would like to use the `@Query` annotation in my repository to find a list of data model objects using a list of ids that are a field in the criteria object, which is nested in the data model object.

Also, want to only get documents between the range of dates specified as well as the limit the number of records returned to the limit specified. Would appreciate any helps, thanks.

```
@Repository
public interface DataModelRepository extends MongoRepository<DataModel, String>{

@Query("{'Criteria.Id' :{ $in: ?0},{'Criteria.DateTimeSearch' : { $lt: ?1, $gt: ?2 }},{$limit :?3}")
List<DataModel> findAllBySearchCriteriaId(List<Integer> ids, Date toDate, Date fromDate, int limit);
```

}

Comment: okay. So what is the exception that you are getting with your @Query

Comment: it was returning an empty list. maybe i could use pageable with your answer to set the amout returned dynamically @pvpkiran

Comment: Yes you can use Pageable. But there is nothing wrong with your query. may be you don't have any records matching your @Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by the following query.

```
Page<DataModel> findByCriteria_IdInAndCriteria_DateTimeSearchBetween(
                                                         List<Integer> ids,  
                                                         Date fromDate,
                                                         Date toDate,  
                                                         Pageable pageable);
```

You don't need `@Query`

You can query this method with something like

```
findByCriteria_IdInAndCriteria_DateTimeSearchBetween(...,
                                                           ...,
                                                           ..., 
                                                          new PageRequest(0, 3);
```

Comment: thanks very much for the reply, but i need the amount of records returned to be dynamic. I cant hard code the amount returned.

Comment: okay. So what is the exception that you are getting with your @Query

Comment: That worked, thank you. I cant upvote your answer because i have low rep. But thank you anyway